# Учебники по программирование и хакерство

Tags: книги

Я хочу изучать программирование . Дайте мне учебники    по программирование,  по хакерство по командной строке`  cmd

Comment: _По программирование_
Может стоит сначала выбрать язык программирования для изучения?

_По хакерство_
Прям так дать книгу как взламывать банки?

_По cmd_
Вот краткий курс по командам: http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr05/cos126/cmd-prompt.html

Comment: Счас заминусуют новичка! А ведь вопрос нормальный!

Comment: @Mira он слишком обобщённый, нужна конкретика, на какой ЯП учебники (в интернетах есть куча статей по выбору ЯП), что именно интересует в хакерстве (таки есть несколько видов "хакеров")

Comment: @Perkovec но явный новичек то не знает ничего о языках и тем более не может выбрать. Надо книжку не по конкретному языку ему, а в общем, ну не знаю - облегченную версию Кнута :) В любом случае вопрос о том "где мне взять знания" в 100 раз лучше вопроса "сделайте за меня домашку"

Comment: @Mira так я и говорю, что в интернете куча статей как выбрать язык и по каким критериям. Мы же не знаем для чего ему надо программировать, для веба, для андроид, для *хакерства*.

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском. В сообщении выше – ссылка на вопрос-указатель списков литературы по различным технологиям.

Comment: Кстати, слово «хакер» давно уже не употребляется в значении «опытный программист». Сейчас так называют исключительно злонамеренных взломщиков. Думаю, таких среди нас нет или очень мало.

Comment: Как ни банально, но начните с Си. 

И для начала прочтите K&R (если думаете о хакерстве, то найдете).  
Книга не самая простая для новичка, но ведь и хакер это не простой кодировщик.
Далее (если, как говорится, "он нужен спецназу") сами разберетесь, куда копать.

Так что, успехов на этом тернистом пути.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дорогой Норайр!

Не имеет смысла искать учебники в общем - тебе для начала надо определится с языком. Чтобы определится с языком - тебе надо определится с задачей - поставить себе цель - написать веб-приложение (сайт), Или просто программу на компьютер - например календарь, выводящий сообщения о будущих события.

Определись с задачей, что ты хочешь для начала сделать, какую программу написать - и тогда тебе подскажут язык и литературу!

Удачи в освоении профессии!

Comment: На вопросы по книжкам мы как правило не пишем ответов, а просто отмечаем дубликатом к общему списку. )

Comment: А сам вопрос засылается в глубокий минус :) ? (вопрос не риторический - правда интересно :) )

Comment: минус не мой, но явно кем-то поставлен с дисциплинарными целями ))

Comment: идея в том, что если отвечать на оффтопик – это провоцирует новые такие же вопросы. Поэтому и отвечать нежелательно. Это особенно важно в вопросах типа "сделайте за меня лабу" или "переведите с фортрана на брейнфак". Один раз делаешь за человека всю работу – он снова приходит и требует.

Comment: Я о том что с самим вопросом предполагается делать - потому что человек, придя на ресурс и задав (пусть и дубль) но нормальный вопрос - получает пачку минусов и больше не возвращается.

Comment: @Mira, а вы предлагаете вытирать сопли каждому новичку?! У ru.SO есть четкие правила, которые одинаково применимы и для "старейшин" и для новичков. Закон равен для всех.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev: сурово )))

Comment: @NickVolynkin, сарказм и суровость - побочный процесс переработки кофе в код ;) Как бы то ни было, варьировать правила в зависимости от объекта применения - это путь в никуда.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev: ну, на то мы и сделали общие списки, чтобы оперативно закрывать дублем. Варьировать правила, конечно, нельзя.

Comment: Конечно, интересный вопрос. Как стать хакером, не имея пока ничего за душой, тут такое еще не обсуждали. И с сложившимся коллективом активистов не будут. Хотите другого? Тогда начинайте активно участвовать (в чате, в мете).

Comment: @DmitriySimushev не вытирать сопли, проигнорируйте если не хотите возится.

Comment: @Mira, вы видимо не понимаете как работает модерация на ru.SO. Тут **нельзя**, слышите, нельзя проходить мимо плохих вопросов, ответов, спама и прочего. Старший брат не придет и не уберет за вами мусор: все нужно делать самим. Иначе мы попросту утонем в мусоре, закончив как многие IT форумы в рунете.

Comment: @Mira если игнорировать, то весь ru.SO будет завален подобными вопросами, тем более вопрос из ряда "легко гуглятся", вот правда, загуглите на русском языке и посмотрите на выдачу.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev а просто закрыть без "утопления" - не работает? (опять же вопрос не риторический, абсолютно серьезный :))

Comment: @Mira а в чем Дмитрий виноват, что вопрос заминусовали?

Comment: @Mira, есть формальные критерии для "+1" и "-1". Я не считаю, что статус новичка должен являться достаточной причиной для игнорирования общих правил

Comment: @Percovets Да не виноват никто, все мои вопросы были собственно о том что очевидно топить наглые или ленивые вопросы, но непонятно зачем топить людей спрашивающих "зеленые" вопросы, если вопрос можно закрыть с нулем. И я получила вполне разумный ответ - что для минусов есть формальные критерии. Ну ок :) мне понятно такое объяснение. Такое сообщество.

Comment: @Mira, у нас есть партия "открывашек", кои представители выдвинули свои кандидатуры на выборы. Мы как раз боремся за менее жёсткое следование формальным правилам. Точнее даже за более мягкие их интерпретации. И да, топить вопрос-дубликат от новичка это странно. Репутацию ниже 1 всё одно не опустить, а засим и воспитательного воздействия никакого)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб пасиб за полезную инфу :)